# Kendo Tree List - refresh with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, telerik, telerik-grid, kendo-treelist

Hi I'm using kendo tree list with angular 1.x as I want to refresh the datascource on some event tried many things but din't got any success they have given a method "refresh()" for Jquery kendo UI tree list control, but its not working for Angular 1.X below is the link of sample code.On button click we are trying to update the datasourse,

```
 http://dojo.telerik.com/AKAco
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to push the item in the dataSource. Check this:

http://dojo.telerik.com/AKAco/2

Comment: if we are doing this way not reflecting the data ?         `$scope.ktl.dataSource = { "AllUser": "mn", "Name": "monica", "Status": "InProgress" }`

Comment: because the widget listens for changes in the datasource and the collection that you pass to the datasource. It is expected.

Comment: So is there any way I can update the datasource because in mine case it is getting updated/refresh on user event.

Comment: the dojo that I shared updates exactly the dataSource.

Comment: Sorry for more trouble, but I'm new to Keno Control, and want to bind the new array of objects [{},{},{}] like this could you please help!!! by updating the dogo...

Comment: Its done now adding this code and its working all good,  `$scope.ktl.setDataSource({
    
 data : $scope.distributionTreeListDataSource
    
 });`